# Create global function in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, function, global

Completely new to C#, so please be patient with me.

I have an application with 2 links. 1 link for anyone to see, 1 for only certain people to see. The code and files and everything are the exact same, the only difference is that if the link contains a certain string in it, it hides certain areas of the page using jquery.

So, I have a lot of different cshtml pages and I don't want to have to rewrite the logic I use to check the username and redirect or not in each page.

I know how to get the username, check if the name is in the 'special list array' and redirect to the appropriate website if not... Just don't know how I can do this efficiently. If 1 person gets added to the array, currently I have to update the array on every page.

Is there a place I can put the function and just call it on each cshtml page?

```
string userName = Environment.UserName;  // System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
string[] arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
bool inArray = false;
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
{
    if (userName == arr1[i]){
        inArray = true;
    }
}
if(inArray)
{
    Response.Redirect("link1");
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("link2");
}
```

Comment: You might want to add the `asp.net` tag.

Comment: you might want to look into authorization and authentication http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part9.htm

Comment: Did you use C# login feature or ur create it on ur own?

Comment: it's an intranet site, so don't want to require a login. there's only a small number of users that should see the special link so was just trying to find a quick way to do this.

Comment: could you show us your current `special array` code - its not clear if this is server side or client side code.